# LINQ: what is the type of a result?

Tags: linq

I have a simple select from a typed dataset:

```
var productlist = from prds in dsProducts.sk_products.AsEnumerable()
                          join prdcat in dsProducts.sk_productscategories.AsEnumerable() on prds.Field<int>("productid") equals prdcat.Field<int>("productid") where prdcat.Field<int>("categoryid") == categoryid
                          select prds;
```

Where productlist is set of records from the Dataset's sk_products datatable. 
I'd like to write a function to filter the records more, with a distinct on one of it's columns:

```
 public List<string, string> GetDistinctManufacturerList(? productlist, int manufacturerid)
    {
       manufacturers = from prdz in productlist where prdz.Field<int>("manufacturerid") == manufacturerid select prdz; [...]
    }
```

With what type of object should I refer to the variable *productlist*?

Comment: Adam had a comment about .AsEnumerable(), it is needed here because it is a disconnected dataset stored in xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an IEnumberable<*selected data type*> - the *selected data type* could be an anonymous type, or in this case, will be your dataset type class.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess something like `IEnumerable<Product>`. And as ck [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824694/linq-what-is-the-type-of-a-result/824697#824697), Product is the name of your LINQ data class.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example... mouse-over the word "var" in Visual studio, and it will display the "Type".

If it's something like 'anonymouse{blahblah}'... then you'll likely have to create a class that you want to convert it to so that you can use it as a function parameter.